# PHP Calculate rank from database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I got a little problem, I've got a database, in that database are different names, id, and coins. I want to show people their rank, so your rank has to be 1 if you have the most coins, and 78172 as example when your number 78172 with coins.

I know I can do something like this:

```
SELECT  `naam` ,  `coins` 
FROM  `gebruikers` 
ORDER BY  `coins` DESC
```

But how can I get the rank you are, in PHP :S ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop and a counter. The first row from MySql is going the first rank,I.e first in the list.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you want something like:

1st - John Doe
2nd - Jane Doe
..
..

right?

See: http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/php-1st-2nd-3rd-4th-5th-6th-php-add-ordinal-number-suffix

Helped me a while ago.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a new varariable

```
$i = "1";
```

pe care o poti folosi in structura ta foreach,while,for,repeat si o incrementezi mereu.
and you use it in structures like foreach,while,for,repeat and increment it

```
$i++;
```

this is the simplest way

Answer (score 0):

No code samples above... so here it is in PHP

```
// Your SQL query above, with limits, in this case it starts from the 11th ranking (0 is the starting index) up to the 20th
$start = 10; // 0-based index
$page_size = 10;
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT  `naam` ,  `coins` FROM  `gebruikers`  ORDER BY  `coins` DESC LIMIT {$start}, {$page_size}");

$data = $stmt->fetchAll();

// In your template or whatever you use to output
foreach ($data as $rank => $row) {
    // array index is 0-based, so add 1 and where you wanted to started to get rank
    echo ($rank + 1 + $start) . ": {$row['naam']}<br />";
}
```

Note: I'm too lazy to put in a prepared statement, but please look it up and use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a session table, you would pull the records from that, then use those values to get the coin values, and sort descending.

If we assume your Session table is `sessions(session_id int not null auto_increment, user_id int not null, session_time,...)` and we assume that only users who are logged in would have a session value, then your SQL would look something like this: (Note:I am assuming that you also have a user_id column on your gebruikers table)

```
SELECT  g.*
FROM  gebruikers as g, sessions as s WHERE s.user_id = g.user_id 
ORDER BY  g.coins DESC
```

You would then use a row iterator to loop through the results and display "1", "2", "3", etc. The short version of which would look like

```
//Connect to database using whatever method you like, I will assume mysql_connect()
$sql = "SELECT  g.* FROM  gebruikers as g, sessions as s WHERE s.user_id = g.user_id ORDER BY  g.coins DESC";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$con); //Where $con is your mysql_connect() variable;
$i = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result,$con)){
    $row['rank'] = $i;
    $i++;
    //Whatever else you need to do;
}
```

## EDIT

In messing around with a SQLFiddle found at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8faa9/6

I came accross something that works there; I don't know if it will work when given in php, but I figured I would show it to you either way

`SET @rank = 0; SELECT *,(@rank := @rank+1) as rank FROM something order by coins DESC`

### EDIT 2

This works in a php query from a file.

```
SELECT @rank:=@rank as rank,
    g.*
FROM
    (SELECT @rank:=0) as z,
    gebruikers as g
    ORDER BY coins DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get the rank of one specific user, you can do that in mysql directly by counting the number of users that have more coins that the user you want to rank:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM  `gebruikers`
WHERE `coins` > (SELECT `coins` FROM `gebruikers` WHERE `naam` = :some_name)
```

(assuming a search by name)

Now the rank will be the count returned + 1.

Or you do `SELECT COUNT(*) + 1` in mysql...